# AngularJS custom directive to build a HTML element dynamically : Issue with binding a dynamic value to ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I've created a custom directive to create HTML elements dynamically. As part of this I'm passing JSON values dynamically to my custom directive to create attributes for the HTML element inside my custom directive. Here, I'm trying to pass a string value to be bound to the `ng-model` but it's considering the dynamic JSON value as a string literal instead of a property to hold the input value.

Another interesting point is, it is working fine if I pass the property name as a hard coded value to the custom directive. But I want to pass a dynamic value to be treated as the property name to be bound to the `ng-model`. Could you please help me on this?

Here is my code and it's not working. Not sure what's wrong. Please suggest me.

Inside my HTML file, below is what I'm using:

Inside my custom directive, I've below snippets:

```
app.directive('myCustomDirective', ['$compile', '$parse', function ( $compile, $parse) {
    return {
             restrict:'E',
             replace : true,
             require: '?ngModel',
    scope: {
       dynamicmodel  :'=dynamicmodel'
    },

     template : '<input type="text" ng-model="dynamicmodel" />',

     link : function(scope, element, attributes, frmCntrl) {

     }

        }
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making several mistakes here. First of all the array does not match the function parameters of your directive:

```
['$compile', '$parse', function ($rootScope, $compile, $parse)
```

I don't see why you need any of these but they at least have to match. For example without `$rootScope`:

```
['$compile', '$parse', function ($compile, $parse)
```

Second the `template` is syntactically incorrect because you use `"` and you are missing a `:`. This is even visible here because the highlighting does not work on your lines starting with `template`.

Then you do not seem to use the name of your directive `mycustomDirective` at all.

My advice would be to check your console and correct all errors that are shown and check back with what you have then. What you posted has too many errors.

Comment: Thanks migg for all your suggestion. Here is the corrected code I've now. Please suggest me how do fix my issue that I've mentioned in my initial post.